# Check text input and show a div accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show different divs depending on the text input. Here is the HTML markup:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="sesam" id="sesam">
<input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Knacken">
<div class="richtig box">Genau! Und jetzt en guete!</div>
<div class="falsch box">Naja, denk doch nochmal scharf nach!</div>
</form>
```

I created a jquery function to fire the different div boxes but it doesnt work:

Here is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
      var code = $('#sesam').val();
      if (code === 'respect') {
      $(".box").hide(1000);
      $(".richtig").show("slow");
      }
      else
      {
      $(".box").hide(1000);
      $(".falsch").show("slow");
      }
    });
});
```

If I use alerts to test it, it works, but not with the divs.

Also jsfiddle gives me some errors: http://jsfiddle.net/c0anytrj/

I just want to check the value and then show one div or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a line: [`e.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) for preventing default submition of form

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var code = $('#sesam').val();
          if (code === 'respect') {
          $(".box").hide(1000);
          $(".richtig").show("slow");
          }
          else
          {
          $(".box").hide(1000);
          $(".falsch").show("slow");
          }
        });
    });
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c0anytrj/2/)

Comment: thank you, Could you explain this a little more or point me to some documentation? It works fine, perfect!

Comment: @Felix i have added a link in answer already. see http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/. Problem with your code was form was submitting if you pressing submit button.

Comment: ah sorry, I didnt realize that!

Comment: if you don't want to use submit, please use type button and click function like this http://jsfiddle.net/1fL3e9e1/